# How to select a dropdown value inside a frame in webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to select a dropdown value which is inside a frame.                 [This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvwoL.jpg)

This is how we write for a link with in frame but i am unable to select a value from dropdown

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("right"));
WebElement el1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Text")));
el1.click();
```

Comment: the name of the frame in your image is not "right", so it probably isn't finding the frame.  and there is no evident link with "Text" in it either, so none of this code should work.  What is the error you get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
    WebElement fr = driver.findElement(By.name("main_b"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(fr);
    WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.name("field"));
    Select sel = new Select(dropdown);
    sel.selectByValue("<Value to be selected>");
```

You can also use wait commands if your page takes some time to load. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

- First, wait for the correct frame (according to HTML code, the name of the frame is `main_b`)
- Next, you don't have a link there (`<a>` tag), so `By.partialLinkText` cannot be used. Use `By.name("field")` instead
- Finally, instead of clicking on it, get a `Select` object: `Select mySelect = new Select(el1);` and choose one of its options using `selectByVisibleText`, `selectByValue` or `selectByIndex` method

So all together looks like this:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("main_b"));

Select mySelect = new Select(
    wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
            By.name("field")
)));

// Select second option by visible text
mySelect.selectByVisibleText("Bacon Anna");

// Same option selected by value
mySelect.selectByValue("16344");

// Same option selected by index
new Select(el1).selectByIndex(1);
```